# Make an input occupy the remaining space?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/334cuL8d/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">

  </div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="John">
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.container{
  width:33%;
  background:grey;
}
.box1{
  background:red;
  width:45px;
  height:32px;
   display:inline-block;
}
input{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:32px;
}
```

What I want to do is make my input more and occupy the remaining space.

My container has a width in percent and Box1 has a width in pixels (should remain).

Can you tell me please what method to use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the [`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the `width` of your `input`, like so:

```
width:calc(100% - 32px);
```

You can check browser support for this function on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to make an input to occupy the remaining space?

You can do this with `box-sizing: border-box` property and a 100% `width` of the input.

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/334cuL8d/3/)

**EDIT**

After clarification of the wanted output, here's a solution with `calc()` function :

```
input{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:32px;
  width: calc(100% - 49px);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/334cuL8d/4/)

Comment: yes but in your example input passes underneath .. he should remain in line with red boxing

Comment: Yes but you didn't specify that. You ask for the **input** to fill the remaing width so I guess there could be a misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
.container {
  width: 33%;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
}
.box1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 45px;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="John">
</div>
```

You can also do this with CSS tables

```css
.container {
  width: 33%;
  background: grey;
  display: table;
}
.box1 {
  background: red;
  width: 45px;
  display: table-cell;
}
input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="John">
</div>
```