# images and type="range" on one line using 100%, withouth actually telling it to

Tags: html, css

I have googeled and tried and can't figure out my problem. I am trying to align 2 pictures and a range type on one line. The range type in the middle should use whatever space the pictures don't. I want to keep the page dynamic, so I don't want to use any size definitions on the range type. The best I can get it to, is to align next to each other.

[image: horizontal alignment]
The code is for css

```
ul.form_align img{
    max-height: 2em;
    max-width: 2em;
}
.form_inline{
    display: inline-block;
    /*white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;*/
}
```

And here the html code

```
<section class="general">
    <ul class="form_align">
        <li>
            <div>
                <div class="form_inline">
                    <img src="img/icon/drive1.png" alt="Drive 1" title="Drive 1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form_inline">
                    <input type="range" name="pref_drive" id="pref_drive" min="0" max="100" value="25" step="1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form_inline">
                    <img src="img/icon/drive100.png" alt="Drive 100" title="Drive 100"/>
                </div>
            </div>                                                
        </li>
        <li>same elements as above for a 2nd topic</li>
        <li>same elements as above for a 3rd topic</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

without inline-block the range is 100%, so what am I doing wrong?

[image: without inline-block]

I have tried display: table/table-row/table-column, but then for some reason everything disapears..... 
I did put everthing in a display:block, no result....

Thanks a ton for any help and hints!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an input occupy the remaining space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858947/make-an-input-occupy-the-remaining-space) (Assuming the images have a defined width).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with `display: flex`. Check below update.

```
<figure>
    <style scoped>
        figure
        {
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            display: flex;
        }
        figure > picture
        {
            flex-shrink: 1; /** use just that you need  **/
        }
        figure > input[type="range"]
        {
            flex-grow: 1; /** use as much space as available **/
        }
    </style>
    <picture>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </picture>
    <input type="range">
    <picture>
        <img src="..." alt="...">
    </picture>
</figure>
```

---

**Updated code:**

```css
ul.form_align img {
  max-height: 2em;
  max-width: 2em;
}
li {
  display: flex;
}
li img {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
li input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="general">
  <ul class="form_align">
    <li>
      <img src="img/icon/drive1.png" alt="Drive 1" title="Drive 1" />
      <input type="range" name="pref_drive" id="pref_drive" min="0" max="100" value="25" step="1" />
      <img src="img/icon/drive100.png" alt="Drive 100" title="Drive 100" />
    </li>
    <li>same elements as above for a 2nd topic
    </li>
    <li>same elements as above for a 3nd topic
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Just put it outside. While answering, I was working on my own project & wont create a stylesheet just for that

Comment: Be calm, I like the scoped styles. It works only in firefox, but it doesn't matter, it's part of W3C specification (that google ignores): https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/style.html

Comment: I used it last year for sometimes before... One day after updated chrome... Every thing turn around! No more working/supported !?

Comment: According to google documentation, you need to activate it in `chrome://flags` and turn on Experimental Web Platform. But still doesn't work with that. Google is making the same that Microsoft's made in the past with IE6. A really crap.

Comment: Bunch of such reason turned the `lover & promoter` of chrome that I was into `fervent open-source defender` user of firefox

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but if I read it correctly, there is little support for scoped http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped

Comment: @TheRealPir just use the styles, not the scoped style tag. It works perfectly.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse me too! Maybe we can try to make a better world instead of a worst world that make developers brain pain.

Comment: [Marcos Pérez Gude](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude)... God will surely bless people as you and I

Comment: Thank you SOO much Salathiel Genèse and Pugazh!!! Amazing, I was struggeling with that for hours! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've always been glad only when I've made others glad. It's a pleasure... Yet keep in mind to prefix and look for support in older browsers

Comment: I thought this was a solution for all browsers with some IE limitation? http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Indeed. I said that because you may be developing an application for public use in which case you have no control on the use browser' version. I was emphasizing on `using prefix`

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.form_align img {
  max-height: 2em;
  max-width: 2em;
}
ul li * {
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type="range"] {
  width: calc(100% - 8em);
}
```

```html
<section class="general">
  <ul class="form_align">
    <li>
      <img src="img/icon/drive1.png" alt="Drive 1" title="Drive 1" />
      <input type="range" name="pref_drive" id="pref_drive" min="0" max="100" value="25" step="1" />
      <img src="img/icon/drive100.png" alt="Drive 100" title="Drive 100" />
    </li>
    <li>same elements as above for a 2nd topic
    </li>
    <li>same elements as above for a 3nd topic
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to have the calc(100%-calculate yourself) dynamic by not specifying the 8em?

Comment: or nothing such as left align, right align and the middle will be used 100%?

Comment: The above solution by Salathiel Genèse can do that!